# Silverlight 4 - Configuring a SqlRoleProvider with a WCF RIA Services Class Library

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

Basically I separated the whole login registration and authentication of the Silverlight Business Application template into a WCF RIA Services class library. But I am not getting this remote server returned NotFound error.

I am supposed to use the SqlRoleProvider and SqlMembershipProvider to hook up the authentication context to my database, instead of the default express database.

I'm confused on the whole app.config and web.config thing. How do I know what goes where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything you want to have affect runtime behavior, or used at runtime must go into web.config. App.config doesn't get applied at runtime.

As such, things like connection strings, provider configuration etc. must all be placed in web.config. Unfortunately there is no VS mechanism to transfer/merge settings from app.config of a class library into a web project.

Answer (score 1):

I would say nothing is impossible! There are more than one ways to dong things, all you need is to think about it.
See: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/Config-Merge.aspx

Or you can use `<connectionStrings configSource="App.Config">` in web.config
Here you are asking web.config to pick settings from another app.config in same directory.